# How to use Android Icons with _dp name?

Tags: android

So I am new to Android development. In iOS you can make a reference to an image "thing.png" and even though you have the following filenames iOS grabs the correct image per the screen res.

```
thing@2x.png
thing.png
thing@3x.png
```

I have icons in Android, from the material design download on GitHub, that are names as follows.

```
ic_cancel_18dp.png
ic_cancel_32dp.png
ic_cancel_48dp.png
```

My question is in Android can I just reference them like @drawable/ic_cancel.png and Android will grab the correct one per the screen res?

Comment: On Android, if you want it to be automatic you give them the same names but put them in distinct folders.  There has to be a relevant example in a question already here somewhere.

Comment: you need to put the files in their respective folder. `drawable-mdpi` ,  `drawable-hdpi`,  `drawable-xhdpi`, with the same name, eg: `ic_cancel.png`. Then android will take care of the rest

Comment: You can't name them all ic_cancel.png. In Androids new material design icon sets they have 3 files with the same name( _18dp.png, _32dp.png, and _48dp.png), in each folder (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi). Only one file can have the name ic_cancel.png.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to put your`.png` files in the relevant directory, and use the **same name**.

For example:

Rename all your files to `ic_cancel.png`.

- In `res/drawable-mdpi`, put your old `ic_cancel_18dp.png`
- In `res/drawable-hdpi`, put your old `ic_cancel_32dp.png`
- In `res/drawable-xhdpi`, put your old `ic_cancel_48dp.png`

In your code, just use `ic_cancel.png` as reference to your image.

For more info, take a look at [Using configuration qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers).